# Android and Live 555 Media Compatibility

Tags: android, streaming, mp4, multimedia, codec

I am very new to live555 media server but I am trying to use it as the backbone to develop a simple video and audio streaming server using android as the client.  I have been desperately testing and have managed to encode a simple test video in H.264 with the extension .264 and streamed it to the handset using the complete live555 media server.  The problem with this is: I constructed the .264 file from a raw avi recording and lowered its spec considerably making the fame size 320X240 and bit rate and frame rate very low. I really want my system to be able to stream any mp4 file which live555 does not support at the moment but is natively supported by android.

Can I implement this formats into the live555 code without knowing too much about encoding or streaming?  If this is not possible for me can some body please advise me on the next steps to take. I am quite sure that trying to encode the mp4 to a raw .264 file upon request at the server is very far from the right answer but atm it is the only format I can stream. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ported successfully live 555 media client to android ? if yes. can i show your source code ? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Android (depending on version) and Live555 support different sets of codecs.

For example if you are using Android 2.2;

- MPEG_4,H263, H264, THREE_GPP

Live555 (as of 2011.03.14 sources )

- MPEG Transport Stream file (with file name suffix ".ts")
- MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream file (with file name suffix ".mpg")
- MPEG-4 Video Elementary Stream file (with file name suffix ".m4e")
- H.264 Video Elementary Stream file (with file name suffix ".264")
- DV video file (with file name suffix ".dv")
- MPEG-1 or 2 (including layer III - i.e., 'MP3') audio file (with file name suffix ".mp3")
- WAV (PCM) audio file (with file name suffix ".wav")
- AMR audio file (with file name suffix ".amr")
- AAC (ADTS format) audio file (with file name suffix ".aac")

If you don't know too much about encoding, I suggest you to use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) library for transcoding one format to another.